# In Coq, how to remove a defined variable from the namespace?

Tags: coq

**In the `coqtop` interactive terminal, how do I remove a name I have defined?**

For example, I can define a bool type with the following.

```
Coq < Inductive my_bool : Type :=
Coq < | my_true : my_bool
Coq < | my_false : my_bool.
```

This works and I get the following output.

```
my_bool is defined
my_bool_rect is defined
my_bool_ind is defined
my_bool_rec is defined
```

But then, if I want to redefine the `my_bool` term, I get `Error: my_bool already exists.`

```
> Inductive my_bool : Type :=
> | my_true : my_bool
> | my_false : my_bool
> | neither : my_bool.
Error: my_bool already exists.
```

Can I drop and redefine the `my_bool` term without exiting the `coqtop` session?

Comment: Yes, see https://coq.inria.fr/refman/vernacular.html#hevea_command131

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Reset my_bool.` to remove it from the environment.

Reference: https://coq.inria.fr/refman/proof-engine/vernacular-commands.html#coq:cmd.reset:

> `Reset` *ident* removes all the objects in the environment since *ident* was introduced, including *ident*. *ident* may be the name of a defined or declared object as well as the name of a section. One cannot reset over the name of a module or of an object inside a module.